# elementary OS and Windows 8 Installed, but I can´t choose wich to select

Tags: release-freya, dual-boot, boot

Well, as the title said, I am looking to learn and be a part of Linux. So I installed elementary OS with Windows 8 too, but my problem is, that when I turn on the computer, the system doesn't ask me which Operating System I want to use, it just starts Windows.

Does anybody know how to fix it ? I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

The next time you should install the OS's in reverse order:First install Windows then the Linux OS. Then you will have the grub menu when you start the computer.

I found a similar question on askubuntu. I did not try it, but it sounds very promising:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu

It is explained for Win7, but I think it will work for Win8 as well.

Remember to disable fastboot on your Win8:https://askubuntu.com/questions/452071/why-disable-fast-boot-on-windows-8-when-having-dual-booting